# ASP.NET Core app on Ubuntu on Rasberry PI with Kestrel Web Server

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, .net-core

i have developed an AST.NET Core app targeting core version "2.0.0-preview1-001875-00"

When i run my app on my Windows dev-machine or an ubuntu desktop everthings works fine. But when i try to run it on ubuntu 16.04 on an raspberry 3 i get an nullrefexception from the kestrel webserver.

The stack is as follows:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HL4AVO08A0CQ", Request id "0HL4AVO08A0D2": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.GetValue(String key)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.

Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This was an bug in the preview version of aspnet core and is fixed as of in 2.0-preview-3

[Github Bug in aspnet core](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6196#issuecomment-307245379)